# How to run Jupyter Notebook without Anaconda on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

There is a lot of information available to run Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda but could not find any info to run Jupyter without Anaconda.

Any pointer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

### Basically the process is as follows:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook # run notebook
```

#### Run a specific notebook:

```
jupyter notebook notebook.ipynb
```

#### Using custom IP or port:

```
jupyter notebook --port 9999
```

#### No browser:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

#### Help:

```
jupyter notebook --help
```

---

Answer from the following sources:

[SOURCE 1](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)
[SOURCE 2](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#running)

Answer (score 5):

See **[Gordon Ball](https://launchpad.net/~chronitis)'s [Jupyter PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chronitis/+archive/ubuntu/jupyter),** the most actively maintained Jupyter PPA as of this writing with support for both Ubuntu 16.04 *and* 18.04 (LTS).

### Installation: It's a Ball

Thanks to Gordon's intrepid efforts, installation of Jupyter under Ubuntu trivially reduces to:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chronitis/jupyter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupyter
```

Doing so installs the `jupyter` metapackage, providing:

- A standard collection of Jupyter packages published by this PPA, including:

  - Jupyter's core and client libraries.
  - Jupyter's console interface.
  - Jupyter's web-based notebook.
  - Tools for working with and converting notebook (ipynb) files.
  - The Python3 computational kernel.
- The `/usr/bin/jupyter` executable.

As [W. Dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7384740/w-dodge)'s [`pip`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50355508/2809027) details, the browser-based Jupyter Notebook UI may then be launched from a terminal as follows – where `'/home/my_username/my_notebooks'` should be replaced with the absolute path of the top-level directory containing all of your Jupyter notebook files:

```
    jupyter notebook --notebook-dir='/home/my_username/my_notebooks'
```

### Why Not Acanaconda or pip?

For Debian-based Linux distributions, the optimal solution is a Debian-based personal package archive (PPA). All other answers propose Debian-agnostic solutions (e.g., Anaconda, `pip`), which circumvent the system-wide APT package manager and hence are non-ideal.

Installing Jupyter via this or another PPA guarantees automatic updates to both Jupyter and its constellation of dependencies. Installing Jupyter via either Anaconda or `pip` requires manual updates to both on an ongoing basis – a constant thorn in the side that you can probably do without.

In short, **PPA** >>>> Anaconda >> `pip`.

Comment: The chronitis repo is at 4.4 and the most recent version is 5.5 so I wouldn't advocate using that repo since it's already 30 weeks old as of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to install Jupyter-Notebook in Ubuntu. One is using Anaconda, the other using pip. Please go through the below added link for details.

http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html